# How to print logs in flutter integration tests running via gradlew

Tags: firebase, android-testing, android-instrumentation, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

I have followed [guide](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/google-firebase-test-lab-integration-for-flutter-integration-tests-38f903d47ac3) to run tests at local as well Firebase test lab.I am using following command to run at local:

```
flutter build apk --debug                                                                                                                  
  ./gradlew app:assembleRcDebugAndroidTest
  ./gradlew app:connectedRcDebugAndroidTest -Ptarget=integration_test/main_test.dart
```

The above command is used to run instrumentation tests on firebase test labs and there as well I don't see any logs.

When I run flutter integration tests using

`flutter driver --target=integration_test/main_test.dart --flavor rc  --driver=test_driver/main_test.dart`

, I am able to see all logs from within tests on console but when running `flutter build..` command I don't see any logs from tests.

I have tried all following ways of printing logs but nothing adds logs to firebase or `flutter build` test runs.

```
 developer.log(
    text,
    name: 'com.app.package',
    error: error,
  );
  stdout.writeln(" Text from stdout: $text");
  print("Normal print statement");

  Logger().d("From logger: $text");
  Logger().e("Error for logging: $text");
```

Can anybody help me how to add logs into `androidTest` or Firebase test lab test logs via flutter?

Is there any argument to `gradlew` which enables logging within build apps?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to find logs of full run (of all tests) in Firebase test labs but not the logs of an individual integration tests.

To get the logs (including the logs from within test cases via `print` statements) navigate as below:

```
Firebase console
> Test lab
> Particular test run
> Devices
> Click on a device under 'Device details'
> Go to Logs tab
```